# Use Raspberry Pi like GoPro, Live Videostream over WiFi direct connection between Pi and Android

Tags: raspberry-pi, p2p, wifi-direct, wifip2p

In the last weeks I experimented with my Raspberry Pi B and with the PiCamera. I had the idea to establish a connection between the RasPi and an Android device or (if it is easier) to a windows notebook without an access point in between, just like the GoPro camera and its App. I would like to have a live stream from the PiCamera to the other device and the possibility to start/stop recording a video or simply take a picture.

The app itself is not my problem, I wrote some simple apps before. But I didn't yet find a tutorial or description how to set up the communication and the stream.

I bought a WiFi dongle ([Fritz!WLAN Stick N - by AVM](http://en.avm.de/products/fritzwlan/fritzwlan-stick-n/)) that supports WiFi direct and my phone (Samsung Galaxy S5 mini) does as well.

My first question is how to set up this stick on Raspbian - yet it is not recognises as a wifi dongle, and the second is how to achieve what I descriebed above.

Could anyone please describe what I can do?

Thanks in advance!

PS: I prefer a description for bash because I use SSH

Comment: you might find the answer to your first question here http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10128/how-to-connect-pi-to-an-android-phone-through-wifi-direct

Comment: I already found this question and watched this video mentioned there but it doesn't work with my wifi adapter.. There is no chip from realtek inside.

Comment: some chips just don't work well with linux. I, too, had to buy a new WiFi dongle because of that. Maybe this site can help you? http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/FRITZ!WLAN_USB_Stick